# Constructor with changing number of arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments

I have a code:

```
Array a1( 1,2,3,4,-1), a2(1,3,5,7,11,-1);
```

How to make `Array` constructor when I know that in the end is always `-1`, amount of numbers before `-1` is unknown and class `Array` has only one constructor?

Comment: Check this link [va_arg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/)

Comment: Consider using variatic templates (on C++11). Or you can develop syntax like this Array a = 1, 2, 3, 4; (overload "=" operator and ","). This is not very safe, but funny syntax.

Comment: @DenisGladkiy, It works for assignment (and that's how Boost.Assign works), but not for initialization (that would just initialize it to 4). Both can be replaced with initializer lists in C++11.